# How to get address of printf function in arm executable

Tags: c++, assembly, arm, elf, relocation

I have assingment to make loader for ARM elf relocatible files. I have managed to parse elf somehow, and managed to make some simple relocations, but i have to do the following and i have trouble. I need to call printf function from inside this ELF file that i am trying to load, and it must be the same printf function as the one from program that is trying to load it. (thats my host program, writen in c++ from ARM arch). How can i get this printf address, and after that how can i relocate symbol in elf file. (I googled and found out that this type of relocation uses 24-bit PC relative addressing) Can anyone help me extract address of printf? 
Thanx in advance!

Comment: Yep i tried something like that but i am having trouble making relocation to new code and i forgot to add type of relocation is #define R_ARM_CALL  28 (where 28 is value in actual file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can understand C++, use the source Luke.

- [arm-reloc-property.cc](http://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/gold/arm-reloc-property.cc?cvsroot=src)
- [arm-reloc-property.h](http://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/gold/arm-reloc-property.h?cvsroot=src)
- [arm-reloc.def](http://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/gold/arm-reloc.def?cvsroot=src)
- [elf32-arm.c](http://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/bfd/elf32-arm.c?cvsroot=src)

See: [Assemblers and Loader](http://www.davidsalomon.name/assem.advertis/asl.pdf), by *David Solomon*. [some pearls of wisdom, some archaic trivia]

As I understand, the `printf` is in the same file and you need to patch the address at run-time.  In this case, the relocation is a *24-bit PC relative* relocation.  The answer is you do nothing in this case.  As the executable and the implementation are both in the same binary, the *24-bit PC relative* 
is already relocated no matter what the load address is.

If you were relocating a *shared library*, the process would be different.

Comment: I sped up the *vxWorks* loader by quite a bit by doing as I have advised.

Comment: Yeah it is run in the same file but in the one that i am trying to load, there is unresolved printf.

Comment: @user1338333 This is a different issue then.  You need to show some **elf** entries and assembler that needs a fix-up as [auselen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1163019/auselen) suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is impossible to understand where are you with your progress, best suggestion would be to point some source code. Check Android's [linker](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/linker/linker.cpp) under [bionic](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/linker/) git.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. When I get (unsigned int)printf I get actual 32-bit address of function. Patch code must be added to end of text section in ELF file. Now on place where 24-bit offset is needed, is inserted offset to patch code. Now this patch code is what is hard to make.

edit:

Something like this:

bl printf should be resolved like bl offset_to_patch_code

patch code should be on bottom of .text section. Watch out when calculating offset pipeline made pc point 2 instructions ahead. Patch code should only server to read into pc address of printf. You do not need to save link register.